# Выполнение LINQ запроса на стороне SQLServer

Tags: c#, linq2sql

Доброго дня!

Имею в наличии клиент на C# и SQLServer 2012. Для подключения использую EF6.

Пишу что-то вроде такого:

```
 using (PCMSContext context = new PCMSContext())
 {
    Dictionary<Guid, pidPV> pPVs = context.pidPV.GroupBy(e => e.idPID).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.date).FirstOrDefault()).ToDictionary(e => e.idPID);
 }
```

Мне важна минимальная загрузка сети и клиента, соответственно у меня возникает вопрос следующего плана:

До какого момента данный LINQ-запрос транслируется в SQL запрос к БД ?

Важно, чтобы операция `g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.date).FirstOrDefault()` выполнялась на стороне БД, т.к. строк `pidPV` в таблице просто громадное количество и мне не нужно их все загружать на клиент и делать операцию сортировки и выборки первого элемента локально на клиенте.

Мне известно, что `ToDictionary()` в любом случае выполняется на стороне клиента, т.к.этот метод расширения работает с коллекцией, реализующей IEnumerable.

Выполняется ли `g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.date).FirstOrDefault()` на стороне SQLServer'а в данном случае ?

Comment: В двух словах: IEnumerable выполяется на стороне клиента, IQueryable - на стороне сервера. Почитать ну скажем: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.4.php

Comment: Да, всё, что до `ToDictionary` выполнится на сервере. Перед выполнением запроса можно на свойство [Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx) навесить логгер и посмотреть, какой именно sql генерируется. Проще всего: `context.Database.Log += Console.WriteLine;`

Comment: На сколько я знаю выполнения метода First происходит на стороне клиента.

Comment: @Bald, ты не прав, либо не до конца прав :-) First - это Top(1)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю, воспользуюсь логгером.

Comment: @Bald а просто `First` не пройдет. Будет ошибка, что ожидалось `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @Bald, я тоже про него, я смотрю на сгенерированный SQL в linqPad по этому запросу

Comment: @Bald есть реализация для IQueryable  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549141(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: В обоих случах в sql будет `TOP (1)`. А уже на клиенте, если из БД пришёл `NULL`, в случае `First` будет выброшено исключение, а в случае `FirstOrDefault` будет `null`.

Comment: Включите просто логгер контекста или профайлер до БД, чтобы запросы поглядеть